# OAuthSwift & Github - what Authorization callback URL should I use?

Tags: ios, swift, github, oauth

I want to setup Github client using OAuthSwift. While setting up the app in the GitHub it asks me for `Authorization callback URL`. What value should I use here ?

Answer (score 2):

You should give the url for `The URL in your application where users will be sent after authorization.`

Check [Web Application Flow](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/) for the details about redirect url. Specially [GitHub redirects back to your site](https://developer.github.com/v3/oauth/#2-github-redirects-back-to-your-site) Part where it is described in details with each parameter details you need to supply in callback.

BR